# Sum multiple SUMIFS in Excel?

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs

I'm trying to sum multiple SUMIFS formulas but it's not working.

When I use the following SUMIF, the answer is 8:

```
=SUMIFS('IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$AB$2:$AB$501,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$P$2:$P$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!$A92,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$Z$2:$Z$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!CN$1)
```

However, when I try to add another SUMIFS (which works by itself and equals 0), and sum those two, the answer changes to 0!

```
=SUM(AND(SUMIFS('IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$AB$2:$AB$501,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$P$2:$P$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!$A92,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$Z$2:$Z$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!CN$1),SUMIFS('IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$AH$2:$AH$501,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$AD$2:$AD$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!$A92,'IN BETWEEN - ORG BASIS'!$AF$2:$AF$501,'ORIGINS OF COOKSTOVES'!CN$1)))
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it wasn't working with AND... but when I removed the AND( ), it worked perfectly.

Comment: "And" returns a boolean (true or false), which, when false, it equal to 0. The "sum" function automatically sums values, separated by commas, together. Thus, when you removed the boolean, it then summed the sumifs together. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!